# ERROR at line 1: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FUN_EMP_DEPT_FK) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm still beginner in sql and i have a problem

```
CREATE TABLE Funtom_employee
(
 emp_ID number(3) CONSTRAINT Fun_emp_PK PRIMARY KEY,
 Emp_firstname varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
 Emp_surname varchar2(50),
 Emp_department number(2) CONSTRAINT Fun_emp_dept_FK REFERENCES Funtom_department(dept_ID),
 emp_street varchar2(50),
 emp_town varchar2(50),
 emp_district varchar2(50),
 Emp_grade number(3) default 4 CONSTRAINT chk_Emp_grd check(Emp_grade between 1 and 9),
 Emp_site varchar2(30) DEFAULT'LONDON'
 );

ALTER TABLE Funtom_employee ADD Employee_status varchar2(10);
ALTER TABLE Funtom_employee ADD Employee_termination date;
ALTER TABLE Funtom_employee ADD Employee_start date;

CREATE TABLE Funtom_department
(
dept_ID number(3) CONSTRAINT Fun_dept_PK PRIMARY KEY,
dept_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

this is my code table code , and

```
insert into funtom_employee (emp_id, emp_firstname, emp_surname, emp_department, emp_street, emp_town, emp_district, emp_grade, emp_site) values (1,'CIEL','PHANTOMHIVE',5,'PHANTOMHIVE MANNOR REGAL AVENUE',null,'LONDON',9,'LONDON');
```

this is the data i need to insert

error showed when i insert the data

```
ERROR at line 1:
```

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FUN_EMP_DEPT_FK) violated - parent key
not found

i couldn't find the problem,the code seem fine to me, can someone helps me to find out the problem? i really appreciate it and thank you very much

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That's not the "likely" reason, that is the reason, please post as an answer.

Comment: Your code works without any problem. Make sure you entered a record into `Funtom_department` table with `dept_ID` = `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message;

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FUN_EMP_DEPT_FK) violated - parent key not found

...basically means that you're trying to break the reference enforced by the foreign key `Fun_emp_dept_FK` which in this case validates that a department the user belongs to actually exists.

In other words, the reason you're getting the error is that *you're trying to add a user that belongs to a department that does not exist*.